# How to parse json string or check if the string present in json in batch script

Tags: json, jenkins

I have following string which is a json response from Jenkins providing info regarding a slave node.

I need to know if the slave node is idle or not. I can see that the node is idle from this code `"idle":true`. How to know if the node is idle form Batch script.

```
{"_class":"hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer","actions":[{"_class":"hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.ComputerConfigHistoryAction"},{}],"assignedLabels":[{"name":"BUILD_SERVER"},{"name":"mster"}],"description":"Master Node","displayName":"master,"executors":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],"icon":"computer.png","iconClassName":"icon-computer","idle":true,"jnlpAgent":false,"launchSupported":true,"loadStatistics":{"_class":"hudson.model.Label$1"},"manualLaunchAllowed":true,"monitorData":{"hudson.node_monitors.SwapSpaceMonitor":{"_class":"hudson.node_monitors.SwapSpaceMonitor$MemoryUsage2","availablePhysicalMemory":1598369792,"availableSwapSpace":54700435035,"totalPhysicalMemory":36507222016,"totalSwapSpace":57579405312},"hudson.node_monitors.TemporarySpaceMonitor":{"_class":"hudson.node_monitors.DiskSpaceMonitorDescriptor$DiskSpace","timestamp":1601446967277,"path":"/tmp","size":1363079168},"org.jenkins.ci.plugins.percentagecolumn.PercentageDiskSpaceMonitor":{"_class":"org.jenkins.ci.plugins.percentagecolumn.PercentageDiskSpaceMonitor$DiskSpace","path":"/home/wcuser/JenkinsSlave","percentage":86.0,"totalSpace":35433480192,"usableSpace":4931731456},"hudson.node_monitors.DiskSpaceMonitor":{"_class":"hudson.node_monitors.DiskSpaceMonitorDescriptor$DiskSpace","timestamp":1601446966760,"path":"/home/cuser/JenkinsSlave","size":4931731456},"hudson.node_monitors.ArchitectureMonitor":"AIX (ppc64)","hudson.node_monitors.ResponseTimeMonitor":{"_class":"hudson.node_monitors.ResponseTimeMonitor$Data","timestamp":1601446966762,"average":46},"hudson.node_monitors.ClockMonitor":{"_class":"hudson.util.ClockDifference","diff":183}},"numExecutors":8,"offline":false,"offlineCause":null,"offlineCauseReason":"","oneOffExecutors":[],"temporarilyOffline":false,"absoluteRemotePath":"/home/wcuser/JenkinsSlave"}
```

I tried to check the if the string `"idle":true` is present with the following command

`curl -X GET --silent -u username:password "http://myjenkins.com/jenkins/computer/master/api/json" | findstr /C:'"idle":true':nul && (Echo.TRUE) || (Echo.FALSE)`

But this is not giving me the correct result.

Is there a way to get to know the info from the json here in batch script.

Comment: I am late by 3 years, but nevertheless. You can install `jq` i.e (`yum install jq` or `apt install jq`) if you're using linux then simply pipe the results to `jq` and catch the idle object. i.e `curl -X GET -s -u "username:password" "http://....../master/api/json" | jq .idle`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [readJSON](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) step:

```
def output = sh returnStdout: true, script: "curl ..."
def parsedOutput = readJSON text: output

if(parsedOutput.idle){
    ...
}
```